# Can Sidekiq run a loop with wait and see a change to the db?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asynchronous, activerecord, sidekiq

I have a sidekiq worker that waits for a change to happen to a record made by a remote client. Something like the following:

```
#myworker async process to wait for client to confirm status

 perform(myRecordID)
   sendClient(myRecordID)
   didClientAcknowledge = false
   while !didClientAcknowledge
    didClientAcknowledge = myRecords.find(myRecordID).status == :ACK_OK
    if didClientAcknowledge 
      break
    end
    # wait for client to perform an update on the record to confirm status
    sleep 5.seconds
   end
   Rails.logger.info("client got the message")
end
```

my problem is that although I can see that the client has in fact performed the acknowledgement and updated the record with correct status update (ACK_OK), my sidekiq thread continues to see the old status for myRecord.

I'm sure my logic is flawed here but it seems like the sidekiq process does not "see" changes to the DB...but if I used my rails console I can see that the client has in fact updated the DB as expected...

Thanks!

## Edit 1

ok so here's a thought, instead of the loop, I'll schedule another call to the worker within 5 seconds... so here's the updated code:

```
perform(myRecordID, retry_count)
   retry_count -= 1
   if retry_count < 1
      return
   end
   sendClient(myRecordID)
   didClientAcknowledge = false
   if !didClientAcknowledge
    didClientAcknowledge = myRecords.find(myRecordID).status == :ACK_OK
    if didClientAcknowledge 
      Rails.logger.info("client got the message")
      return
    end
    # wait for client to perform an update on the record to confirm status
    myWorker.perform_in(5.seconds)
   end
   Rails.logger.info("client got the message")
end
```

This seems to work, but will test a bit more..one challenge is having a retry count which means I need to maintain some sort of variable between calls to the worker...

*edit2* possibly this can be done by passing in the time to the first call and then checking if a timeout has been surpassed before invoking the next instance...assuming time does not stand still as well inside the async call...

*edit3* Adding the retry_count argument allows us to control how many times this worker will be spawned...

Comment: instead of sleep or retry the worker, why don't you put in the "acknowledgement" action a call to thing you want to do?

Comment: The clients are on 4G networks and sometimes they don't acknowledge...the retry basically performs the send again (over actioncable which appears to be lossy, unless perhaps I'm misusing actioncable...which wouldn't be a first XD )...